# Pyspark - Error while copying files from local(Edge node) to HDFS location

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to copy files from Local to HDFS location in pyspark using following code.

```
sc = SparkSession.builder.appName("HDFSPySparkRead").getOrCreate()
sparkCont = sc.sparkContext
URI           = sparkCont._jvm.java.net.URI
Path          = sparkCont._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
FileSystem    = sparkCont._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
Configuration = sparkCont._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration


fs = FileSystem.get(URI("hdfs://gcgmwdcuat:8020"), Configuration())
fs.copyFromLocalFile('/home/ak18191/ar_new.txt', 'hdfs://gcgmwdcuat:8020/user/ak18191/')
```

Getting error:

**py4j.Py4JException: Method copyFromLocalFile([class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]) does not exist**

I also tried below code

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'hdfs dfs -put -f /home/ak18191/ar_new.txt hdfs://gcgmwdcuat:8020/user/ak18191/'
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

But getting file not found error. The command is executing successfully in spark-shell. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyFromLocalFile` takes two Path objects, not strings

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html

Answer (score 4):

solution1 -subprocess

```py
def copy_from_local(local_file, hdfs_file, logger):
    import subprocess
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["hdfs", "dfs", "-copyFromLocal", "-f", local_file, hdfs_file])
    proc.communicate()

    if proc.returncode != 0:
        logger.info("copyFromLocal {} to {} error".format(local_file, hdfs_file))
        return False
    else:
        logger.info("copyFromLocal {} to {} success".format(local_file, hdfs_file))
        return True
```

solution2 -py4j

```py
def copy_from_local_file(sc, logger, local_file, hdfs_file, delSrc=True, overwrite=True):
    # copyFromLocalFile(boolean delSrc, boolean overwrite, Path src, Path dst)
    Path = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
    try:
        getFileSystem(sc).copyFromLocalFile(delSrc, overwrite, Path(local_file), Path(hdfs_file))
        logger.info("copyFromLocal {} to {} success".format(local_file, hdfs_file))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        logger.info("copyFromLocal {} to {} error".format(local_file, hdfs_file))


def getFileSystem(sc):
    # Prepare a FileSystem manager
    FileSystem = sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
    fs = FileSystem.get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
    return fs
```

and you can get the py4j jvm [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) objet and do file operation in above

```
getFileSystem(sc) = {JavaObject} DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_15601292_17, ugi=jrsyb@HADOOP.COM (auth:KERBEROS)]]
 access = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e7d0>
 addCacheDirective = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432610>
 addCachePool = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435610>
 addDelegationTokens = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44323d0>
 allowSnapshot = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432990>
 append = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435c90>
 areSymlinksEnabled = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442cf10>
 cancelDeleteOnExit = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432850>
 clearStatistics = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e410>
 close = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442eb90>
 closeAll = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432c10>
 closeAllForUGI = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432150>
 completeLocalOutput = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435190>
 concat = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e450>
 copyFromLocalFile = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e650>
 copyToLocalFile = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e990>
 create = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432790>
 createEncryptionZone = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432310>
 createNewFile = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44321d0>
 createNonRecursive = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432f90>
 createSnapshot = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e290>
 createSymlink = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432a50>
 delete = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435390>
 deleteOnExit = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ec10>
 deleteSnapshot = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e110>
 disallowSnapshot = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ee50>
 enableSymlinks = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ed90>
 equals = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ef90>
 exists = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432050>
 finalizeUpgrade = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432890>
 get = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ea10>
 getAclStatus = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432a90>
 getAllStatistics = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e8d0>
 getBlockSize = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e1d0>
 getCanonicalServiceName = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442cdd0>
 getChildFileSystems = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435410>
 getClass = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432290>
 getClient = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44358d0>
 getConf = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435750>
 getContentSummary = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44357d0>
 getCorruptBlocksCount = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432550>
 getDataNodeStats = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432950>
 getDefaultBlockSize = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432d50>
 getDefaultReplication = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e210>
 getDefaultUri = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435490>
 getDelegationToken = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435c50>
 getDiskStatus = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ee10>
 getEZForPath = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435710>
 getFileBlockLocations = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e2d0>
 getFileBlockStorageLocations = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e890>
 getFileChecksum = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432d10>
 getFileLinkStatus = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435a90>
 getFileStatus = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e250>
 getFileSystemClass = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e850>
 getHomeDirectory = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44326d0>
 getInotifyEventStream = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432690>
 getLength = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435b90>
 getLinkTarget = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442cfd0>
 getLocal = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ef10>
 getMissingBlocksCount = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435450>
 getName = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432350>
 getNamed = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ea90>
 getRawCapacity = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435950>
 getRawUsed = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e690>
 getReplication = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e150>
 getScheme = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ec90>
 getServerDefaults = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432650>
 getSnapshotDiffReport = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e0d0>
 getSnapshottableDirListing = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435a50>
 getStatistics = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432490>
 getStatus = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442cf50>
 getStoragePolicies = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432e90>
 getUnderReplicatedBlocksCount = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ced0>
 getUri = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44350d0>
 getUsed = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432f10>
 getWorkingDirectory = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44329d0>
 getXAttr = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432410>
 getXAttrs = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432b10>
 globStatus = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435810>
 hashCode = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435510>
 initialize = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44320d0>
 isDirectory = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435150>
 isFile = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ed10>
 isFileClosed = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435650>
 isInSafeMode = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e4d0>
 listCacheDirectives = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442edd0>
 listCachePools = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435210>
 listCorruptFileBlocks = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432ad0>
 listEncryptionZones = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432750>
 listFiles = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435690>
 listLocatedStatus = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442eb50>
 listStatus = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432590>
 listXAttrs = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e550>
 makeQualified = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435b50>
 metaSave = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442cd50>
 mkdir = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e310>
 mkdirs = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e5d0>
 modifyAclEntries = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435b10>
 modifyCacheDirective = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435590>
 modifyCachePool = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435350>
 moveFromLocalFile = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432510>
 moveToLocalFile = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e510>
 newInstance = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432bd0>
 newInstanceLocal = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432710>
 notify = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e910>
 notifyAll = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435250>
 open = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432210>
 printStatistics = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e190>
 recoverLease = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432fd0>
 refreshNodes = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44355d0>
 removeAcl = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ce50>
 removeAclEntries = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e390>
 removeCacheDirective = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432a10>
 removeCachePool = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e710>
 removeDefaultAcl = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ce10>
 removeXAttr = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ec50>
 rename = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442ee90>
 renameSnapshot = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432d90>
 resolvePath = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e9d0>
 restoreFailedStorage = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432810>
 rollEdits = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432dd0>
 rollingUpgrade = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44324d0>
 saveNamespace = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435c10>
 setAcl = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44352d0>
 setBalancerBandwidth = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e3d0>
 setConf = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44359d0>
 setDefaultUri = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432ed0>
 setOwner = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e050>
 setPermission = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442eb10>
 setQuota = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432c90>
 setReplication = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435990>
 setSafeMode = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435890>
 setStoragePolicy = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44354d0>
 setTimes = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435050>
 setVerifyChecksum = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432b90>
 setWorkingDirectory = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432e50>
 setWriteChecksum = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44351d0>
 setXAttr = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b44328d0>
 startLocalOutput = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4432190>
 supportsSymlinks = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b4435ad0>
 toString = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4dbcbdc10>
 wait = {JavaMember} <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7ff4b442e750>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the -f parameter:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'hdfs dfs -put /home/ak18191/ar_new.txt hdfs://gcgmwdcuat:8020/user/ak18191/'
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

If you still getting file not found, make sure that you typed the file name correctly by running the following command on the machine:
`hdfs dfs -ls /home/ak18191/ar_new.txt`

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put